# Google Apps Script triggered by another user on my sheet isn't opening a form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a Google Sheet to track projects that I'd like to share with other people in my company.  I've developed a UI using html forms that walks the user through questions to get the necessary data for project costing.

The forms are opened by a custom menu - and that works great for both me and other users (in this case actually me using a different Google account).

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('PROJECT COSTING TOOL')
    .addItem('Create a New Proposal', 'newProposal')
    .addItem('Create a New Version of this Proposal', 'copyProposal')
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Edit This Proposal')
          .addItem('Edit Project Background', 'editBackground')
          .addItem('Edit Project Complexity', 'editProject')
          .addItem('Edit Category Complexity', 'editCategory'))
    .addToUi();
}
```

For example, selecting "Edit Project Complexity" triggers the editProject function in Apps Script. "Edit Category Complexity" triggers the editCategory function.  Both work great for any user.

Those functions open html forms using openForm:

```
function editProject(curProp) {
  console.log('Opening editProject for Project #' + curProp);
  curProp = curProp || SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('CurrentProposal').getValue();
  console.info('curProp is now ' + curProp);
  var projRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('Data_Projects');
  openForm('frmProject', 'Edit Project Complexity',700,800,rowToJson(projRange,findRow(projRange,curProp)));
}
```

You can see the code checks if a project # is passed via e and if not it looks it up in the Sheet itself.  Within each html form are buttons that save changes to the Sheet, close the form, and open another form (Next or Prev).  Here's where I'm having trouble.  For both myself and non-owner users, the function to save & close runs great.  And when I trigger the editProject function, that works fine too. But it never makes it to openForm.

```
function saveCategoryPrev(e) {
  console.log('SaveCategoryPrev has been run: ' + e);
  var projID = saveCategory(e);
  console.info('saveCat is done. Back to sCP with Project #' + projID)
  editProject(projID);
}
```

Running as myself (the owner), it works great. Running as another user, does everything up to the openForm and quits without error.  Here's the log from that case:

```
D  SaveCategoryPrev has been run: [[7,<other data>]]  for proj [undefined 
D  SaveCategory has been run: [[7,<other data>]] 
D  project is 7 
D  Data Array = <some data>
D  saveCategory: 537ms 
I  saveCat is done. Back to sCP with Project #7 
D  Opening editProject for Project #undefined 
I  curProp is now 7
```

When I run it as myself you can see the next step is triggered:

```
D  SaveCategoryPrev has been run: [[7,<other data>]] for proj [undefined]
D  SaveCategory has been run: [[7,<other data>]] 
D  project is 7 
D  Data Array = <some data>
D  saveCategory: 370ms 
I  saveCat is done. Back to sCP with Project #7 
D  Opening editProject for Project #7 
I  curProp is now 7 
D  onLoad = {"Proposal ID":7,"Opportunity ID":"","Ver #":1,"Project Start":"2019-05-01T04:00:00.000Z","Duration (mo)":2,"Sales Engineer":"...}
```

openForm:

```
function openForm(formName, formTitle, fmHeight, fmWidth, paramData) {
  fmHeight = fmHeight || "450";
  fmWidth = fmWidth || "800";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(formName).setHeight(parseInt(fmHeight)).setWidth(parseInt(fmWidth));
  if (paramData) {html.append("<div id='gsParam' style='display:none;'>" + paramData + "</div>");}
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, formTitle);
}
```

What am I missing? What's the difference metween myself and another user that has accepted authorization?  What's the difference between opening a form using the menu and opening it via code?

Comment: What does the execution log look like? And also what does [stack logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) look like?

Comment: That is the stack logging, but when I copy and paste it strips out the timestamp. D=debug, I=info.  The execution transcript is weird - for myself it's very short but for the non-owner user it's dozens of lines ling detailing every bit of data it's reading from the Sheet

Comment: [19-05-03 17:23:36:018 EDT] Starting execution
[19-05-03 17:23:36:029 EDT] console.log([onLoad = [object Object], []]) [0.002 seconds]
[19-05-03 17:23:36:031 EDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-05-03 17:23:36:136 EDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Project Data]) [0.104 seconds]
[19-05-03 17:23:36:136 EDT] Sheet.getRange([B22]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-03 17:23:36:137 EDT] Range.setValue([onLoad = [object Object]]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-03 17:23:36:370 EDT] Execution succeeded [0.112 seconds total runtime]

Comment: Can you please share the code for `openForm()`? It sounds like you're trying to get one user to open a new page for another user, but that's not possible.

Comment: I totally forgot that was a UDF. I edited it into the question. To your 2nd part, what do you mean when you say one user open a page for another user? An html page opened by a user triggers a function in the gs that should open another html page.